# Are comments moderated on blog.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc, blog

About an hour or two ago I went and added a comment to the [Recalc Blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) on blog.stackoverflow.com.

The comment has still not shown up.  I thought maybe it got lost in translation, so I tried to add it again.  (I had saved a copy.)  When I did this it told me that I had already submitted this comment (so I know it got received).

Are comments moderated? Or are they not allowing comments on this post anymore?

NOTE: This was my comment (in case someone has any idea why this would not be allowed to be posted).  It was in response to this post by Jeff: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/#comment-45446

---

> > I should note that this question rebalancing is based
> > on 6+ months of meta.stackoverflow.com feedback on
> > the subject — so it is coming from the community, as
> > well.

True that there was a problem with people asking lots of lame questions.  But the idea to half all question points was not from meta (at least as far as I could see).  It got posted on meta by Jeff and then cemented in 5 hours later (by posting it as a plan on the blog).

So the point that "this is just another reminder, all this talk about “it’s all about the community!” to the contrary, [this change shows] who’s really in charge" has some weight.

I agree with JohnMcG.  Jeff built it, he can do what he wants with it.  But, while the community gets to comment on meta all they want, in the end it is an owned product and unilateral decisions can be (and were) made and put in to effect with little to no feed back from the "community".

Comment: Did you have links in it? Sometimes comments with links have to be manually approved, it seems.

Comment: I had no links.

Comment: Jeff has been known to delete comments from the blog in the past. There's no way of telling if that's the case here, or if there is some sort of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question, no they are not moderated ahead of time. Sometimes I moderate them after the fact if they aren't constructive or at least funny in a non-malicious way.

As to the current lack of comments, this was an error in the latest version of WP-ReCaptcha. Comments were all being held for some reason-- I think because the WP-SuperCache was caching the old interface for WP-ReCaptcha.

Anyway, fixed now, all pending comments were published.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're moderated, but there's also a [spam trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33117/are-comments-broken-on-blog-stackoverflow-com) that sometimes gets clogged or something (or maybe Jeff just has it tuned to filter out comments about people gaming the Taxonomist badge).

Answer (score 0):

I just left two comments, one to the above linked post, and one to the latest podcast post.  Neither comment showed up.

The last comment was on the 22nd, and things were getting a bit out of hand, so it wouldn't surprise me if they were being moderated.

I'd expect them to just close comments on that one post, though, and direct people to continue the conversation on meta, and leave the other posts alone.

Could be broken.

Comment: My podcast comment was witty, too.  `for(balmer=0;balmer<65;balmer++) printf("Backups!!!\n");` - ah well.