# Comments added for Stack Exchange blog post not displayed

Tags: support, blog, stack-exchange

I try to add a comment for Stack Exchange [recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/#comment-96119),
but it's not displayed and I didn't got any error/warning message after submit.

As per this thread [comments moderated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43868/173406) blog issue with WP-ReCaptcha is fixed!.

**How do I know what happened to that comment?**

- it's moved to spam?
- it's under moderation?
- blog has an issue(for comments)?